# Error in Build server error MSB3086: Task could not find "AL.exe" using the SdkToolsPath "" or the registry key

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, bamboo

In my build server I am getting the following error. I am building using the Build Tools msbuild that is in the folder "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\Bin\amd64\MSBuild.exe"

1. Framework version is 4.6.1
2. I am using Bamboo for our CI.
3. Project is a Visual Studio 2015 project

Comment: Reinstall your `Windows SDK`! Which OS your are using?

Comment: @Smartis Windows Server 2012 R2

Comment: https://dev.windows.com/en-us/downloads/windows-8-1-sdk

Comment: It worked!! Can u pls post it as answer. I was under the impression that I only needed .Net f/w and build tools for building in build server. I had installed .net f/w using dev pack still this didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`AL.exe` is a part of the Windows SDK.

For Windows Server 2012 try to reinstall the Windows SDK from [here](https://dev.windows.com/en-us/downloads/windows-8-1-sdk).